# How to fix django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: python, django

Seen this question already asked but still no solution working for me.

My docker-compose:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes: 
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGREES_PASSWORD=password

  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/books
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

my requirements.txt

```
Django>=3.2
psycopg2-binary>=2.8
```

my settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER' : 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD' : 'postgres',
        'HOST' : 'db',
        'PORT' : 5432,
    }
}
```

my dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
WORKDIR /books
COPY requirements.txt /books/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /books/
```

the error that is showing  on my terminal

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
web_1  |     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
web_1  | django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not translate host name "db" to address: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

Comment: follow this link https://dev.to/mungaigikure/how-to-set-up-postgres-in-your-django-project-575i

Comment: make sure your postgre db is running

Comment: Thank You. Had a typo on docker-compose and my password were different